# How can hide blue color background of selected text in notepad programmaticaly delphi, vc++

Tags: windows, delphi

I need to copy paste text from notepad but i wish that blue background of selected text remain white, is that possible?

Following code selects and copies notepad text to clipboard

```
Wnd := FindWindowHandleByTitle('Notepad');
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0,  0, 0);
keybd_event(ord('A'), 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(ord('A'), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
sleep(200);
//
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0,  0, 0);
keybd_event(ord('C'), 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(ord('C'), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: I'd obtain the text programmatically instead (e.g., using `WM_GETTEXT`). For instance, the user will be very angry if you clear his clipboard.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Indeed, I've faced an extremely annoying experience with an application, where the developer used the clipboard to copy text for debugging, and forgot to disable it, and it was even in a loop, so as long as that app was running, it kept overwriting whatever I had in my clipboard, rendering it useless.

Comment: Does edit control of Notepad have focus? ie will resetting `ES_NOHIDESEL` be of any help?

Comment: What is the real problem?

Comment: I need to monitor skype text messages, WM_GETTEXT does not work, only copy paste is working but background of selected text should remain hidden